# How can I further diagnose "bluscreen/~restart on awakening" problems that take place after upgrading HDD or RAM?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, memory, ssd, bsod

I've got 2 similar problems with hardware/drivers/?? which I'm not sure how to address or diagnose, both with the same (Lenovo ThinkPad 460 Yoga) laptop.

The first one took place when I **tried to switch the** (1TB) **HDD with a** (1TB Samsung 850 Pro) **SSD**. The laptop **started to bluescreen** (or restart as if the power was switched off and on) **frequently after awakening** (each time I noticed BSODs' code it was either `DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION` or `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`). After 2 or 3 weeks of working with that I've noticed that if I close all apps that consume *some* resources (well, notepad++ is not among them), it doesn't bluescreen. However, that wasn't an acceptable limitation and I gave up and migrated back to HDD.

Now, 3 days ago I've **switched 8GB RAM with 16GB RAM** from Crucial with the same speed and frequency as the original one. And **the "bluescreen/restart on awakening" problem arose again**. Unlike with SSD which may have some problems with data migration and be not compatible with the laptop (officially Lenovo writes compatibility with HDD up to 1TB and SSD up to 512MB), the RAM shouldn't have any compatibility problems (same form-factor, SODIMM, same type, DDR3L, same frequency and speed, I've seen even a video on YouTube where they switch RAM to that very model by Crucial), and I'm suspecting I should try to tweak some settings to make things work. Unfortunately, I have no idea what settings to try to tweak.

Do you have any idea what could be wrong, what I can try to tweak or how to diagnose the problem further?

PS I've checked BIOS, it shows the correct amount of RAM and also run some Lenovo diagnostics for RAM and those went well..

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a sad answer, albeit may be useful.

Assuming swapping your storage media made you do a reformat / clean install.

If you get a BSOD, on Win10, after a clean install and updates:

**95% - it's a hardware problem.**

If it started happening with yet another component, I would point towards **a faulty motherboard.**

Good luck, computers are finicky.

Comment: well, I didn't clean install, but the problem with 16GB RAM (with HDD) may suggest a hardware problem indeed.. The question is, how to diagnose it?

Comment: Clean install...